# How to manually install Broadcom BCM4360 driver on Ubuntu on MacBook Air

Tags: drivers, wireless, broadcom

I have a MacBook Air (mid 2013) with Ubuntu 16.04 installed on it. It is not detecting any WiFi, upon investigation I think the reason is that the driver for the wireless interface is not installed by default in Ubuntu as it is properietery. Exact version of the wireless interface on my MacBook Air is BCM 4360, here is the output of the **lspci** command:-

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
```

As there is no Ethernet or any other way to connect to the internet, I cannot run apt-get install. Is there any way I can manually install the required driver?

Comment: It worked! I did search for a long time but idk why didn't find this link ... maybe 'offline' was the keyword. Thanks.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, as the answer to the other question refers to Ubuntu 14.04. and in the comments it is mentioned that the problem should not even exist later because it was fixed. Now, I run 16.04 and have the same chip and also no wifi. Also, the other question relates to 'offline'.